# Change the CodeName of Template Worksheet: "Run-time Error 1004" Expecting object to be local on line ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.Name = "VBAProject"

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

What is VBAProject? Is VBAProject my Program.xlsm file because if I replace with that I get the same error.

I tried adding to find the name:

```vb
Dim myString As String
myString = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.Name
```

But got a similar error.

I am trying to change the CodeName of my Template Worksheet WS0000 to WS0002, WS0003... WS0nnn within my VBA code.

```vb
Sub ChangeCodeName()
    Dim wbk As Object, Sheet As Object
    ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.Name = "VBAProject"
    Set wbk = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.CodeName)
    wbk.Name = "WS0000"
    Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).CodeName)
    Sheet.Name = "WS0002"
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `VBProject`?  [Workbook.VBProject property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.vbproject).  If you want to change the name, you may need to enable the checkbox in the trust center for allowing access to the VBA project.

Comment: Do you have lists of the initial code names and the new code names? Or do you want to rename each sheet and you have a list of the new code names? Please explain the renaming logic. Also, share if this will be applied to sheets (including charts) or just to worksheets. `"VBAProject"` is useless (irrelevant) unless you change it. If the code is in the workbook where you will be renaming the sheets, then you should use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`. Please add the additional information to your post.

Comment: Thank you VBasic2008. Let me explain. I have a Workbook called, “UserTemplate”. It has one “Worksheet”, name “0”, Codename “WS0000”. I have another Workbook, “TargetUser”, with an initial Worksheet, Name “1”, Codename “WS0001”. Periodically, I add sequentially numbered Worksheets; 2, 3, 4 etc., to “TargetUser”. I copy Worksheet “WS0000” to the sequentially numbered “Worksheets” and I would like to rename their Codename’s “WS0002”, “WS0003” etc. This project never leaves my computer, so I could stick with the names 1, 2, 3, etc., but you never know what could happen,  better safe than sorry.

Comment: Thanks to both you guys, Cyril and VBasic2008, I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving image to turn on the trust access to the VBA project, under Trust Center -> Macro Settings -> Developer Macro Settings, as outlined in my comment to the post:

[image]